# PHP Select average between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to select the average time between 2 dates in php from 2 different tables.

i have this:

```
$sql="select *, avg(end_date - start_date) as avg_days from tickets where deleted = '' and DAY(datetime) = '04' and MONTH(datetime) = '".date("m")."' and YEAR(datetime) = '".date("Y")."' group by assigned_to";
```

but i want to be able to work out the average 'response' time from the `datetime` column in the `tickets` table and the `startdate` column in the `ticket_updates` table.

the `ticket_seq` in the `ticket_updates` table links with the `ticketnumber` column in the `tickets` table so i need to select the first row created from the `ticket_updates` table that links with the selected row from the `tickets` table

i have tried:

```
$sql="select tickets.*, avg(tickets.datetime - ticket_updates.timestart) as avg_days from tickets, ticket_updates where tickets.ticketnumber = ticket_updates.ticket_seq and deleted = '' and DAY(datetime) = '04' and MONTH(datetime) = '".date("m")."' and YEAR(datetime) = '".date("Y")."' group by assigned_to";
```

but nothing is returned and when i run in mysql i get:

```
 #1052 - Column 'datetime' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: see my question edit..

Comment: The error message means you have to qualify the field datetime with one of the tables in your where clause.  You know how to do that I trust.

Comment: im not too sure how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue by using this query:

```
$sql="
SELECT 
    tickets.*, 
    avg(tickets.datetime - ticket_updates.timestart) as avg_days 
FROM 
    tickets, ticket_updates 
WHERE 
    tickets.ticketnumber = ticket_updates.ticket_seq 
AND deleted = '' 
AND DAY(tickets.datetime) = '04' 
AND MONTH(tickets.datetime) = '".date("m")."' 
AND YEAR(tickets.datetime) = '".date("Y")."' 
GROUP BY 
    tickets.assigned_to
";
```

Comment: Accept your own answer if it fixed the issue.

Comment: i would love to but i cant for 2 days